# Append Data Type to Plist

Tags: ios, swift

I am parsing data and instansiating struct each Time root element (objstation) is parsed and encoding to DATA to write to plist

XML Structure

```
<objStation>
        <StationDesc>Killester</StationDesc>
        <StationAlias/>
        <StationLatitude>53.373</StationLatitude>
        <StationLongitude>-6.20442</StationLongitude>
        <StationCode>KLSTR</StationCode>
        <StationId>101</StationId>
    </objStation>
    <objStation>
        <StationDesc>Clontarf Road</StationDesc>
        <StationAlias/>
        <StationLatitude>53.3629</StationLatitude>
        <StationLongitude>-6.22753</StationLongitude>
        <StationCode>CTARF</StationCode>
        <StationId>109</StationId>
    </objStation>
```

I am using the following method in my struct to encode and write to plist, however only the current instance of the struct is saved to the plist, I am wondering how to append to the plist, so all root elements are saved to the plist, I have played around with various swift native functions around the DATA type but have had no joy.
Maybe I should be using an array of dictionaries rather than a struct for this?

```
         //mark properties, update as necssary, based on xml strucutre
struct StationsEncoder: Codable {

    var station: String
    var latitude: String
    var longitude: String
    var code: String
    var id: String

    //MARK: Initialization

    init(station: String, latitude: String, longitude: String, code: String, id: String ) {
        self.station = station
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.code = code
        self.id = id
    }

    //mark initializers
    // lets try encode our data
        func encoder(){
                let stationStruct = StationsEncoder(station: station, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude, code: code, id: id)
                let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
                encoder.outputFormat = .xml
                do {
                let data = try encoder.encode(stationStruct)
                try data.write(to: CreatePlist.shared.plistURL)

                } catch {
                // Handle error
                print(error)
                print( CreatePlist.shared.plistURL)
                }
                }


}
```

Comment: You can't append to a plist. You need to load the current plist data, append to that array or dictionary, then write out the updated array or dictionary overwriting the plist with the new version.

Comment: You might want to consider using a database instead of a plist depending on the amount of data and your app's needs.

Comment: Thanks Maddy for explaining I cannot append to plist. Thought I maybe able to append to the DATA object and then write to the plist. I tried some native class methods provided for DATA type, but they did not seem to add to the data incrementally. I suppose I got carried away with trying to use a codable struct, but maybe they are just better for instances rather than trying to iterate through a full  data set. I have only 20 xml root elements in this data (re using database). So it sounds like I should get the data into an array of dictionaries and then write entire lot to plist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with a tiny bit of code using `PropertyListSerialization` method (thanks again to Maddy who saved time pointing out that you cannot append to a plist). The best option I found was to append to a dictionary first, then write out entire dictionary to plist:

```
do {
    let writeData = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: [parsedDictionary], format: .xml, options:0)
    //note CreatePlist.shared.plistURL is my URL, just replace with yours, I am accessing a singleton class that has the URL here for convenience:     
    try writeData.write(to: CreatePlist.shared.plistURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```